Importing polygons from a text file to draw over the TIFF image (GeoTIFF)
I am working on a project in which detection happens for the ships in the TIFF images.
After detection, rotated bounding boxes are plotted over the TIFF images as a layer of the fabricJS.
Due to requirements, I need to plot these bounding boxes directly on the TIFF image.
Since the image may have upto 10gb of size, it seems too costly to draw boxes directly on the image without losing any geoInformation.
Is there a way I can do this??
Also I've saved the vertices of the boxes saved into a text file.
How can I get the problem resolved?

What you want to achieve is not clear to me: burn the polygon as part of the GeoTiff, or open the GeoTiff in QGIS and display the polygons as another vector layer on top of the GeoTiff ? In either case, what is the format of the textfile where the boxes are saved ?

"detection happens"? Please expand a little on this.

Hi @Kasper thanks for replying and sorry if i couldn't explain it well.
Let me explain:
I'm currently developing an application that's intended to detecting object in TIFF images, which contains geographical information. Once the algorithm runs on this image, it detects object (I hope it explains "detection happens"). To represent these detected objects accurately, the application saves their coordinates into a text file.
Now, the challenge is to visualize these polygons on top of the original image without affecting its quality, size, or the geographical information embedded within it.

let me be more clear with the data:
ID,X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3,X4,Y4
1,3835.2929999999997,144.98,3835.0789999999997,157.252,3756.184,155.874,3756.399,143.603
2,2527.149,1450.45,2538.629,1457.078,2488.677,1543.596,2477.198,1536.969
3,2618.779,1631.7269999999999,2631.094,1640.674,2564.542,1732.275,2552.227,1723.328
4,3919.17,151.944,3918.99,161.983,3860.862,160.968,3861.0370000000003,150.93
this is the data saved in csv file.
